# Action Template Error (Stack level too deep) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application using these following lines is causing ActionTemplate:Error (stack level too deep). All was working fine with the same piece of code in place, suddenly application started throwing this error.

```
<% if (not flash[:notice].nil? and not flash[:notice].empty?) or (not flash[:warning].nil? and not flash[:warning].empty?) %>
  <center>
    <div style="background-color:lightyellow; border: 1px solid gold; width: 95%; padding: 3px; text-align: left;">
      <font color=green>
        <i>
          <b>
            <%= flash[:notice] %>
            <% if !flash[:warning].blank? %>
              <%= "<BR/>" if !flash[:notice].blank?%>
              <%= image_tag "warning.ico", :size => "32x32" %>&nbsp;<%= flash[:warning] %>
            <% end %>
          </b>
        </i>
      </font>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </center>
  <% flash[:notice] = flash[:warning] = "" %>
<% end %>
```

Error thrown in development log is

```
    ActionView::TemplateError (stack level too deep) on line #182 of app/views/layouts/loggedin.rhtml:
    179:                    </font>
    180:                    <br/>
    181:            </div>
    182:            <% if (not flash[:notice].nil? and not flash[:notice].empty?) or        (not flash[:warning].nil? and not flash[:warning].empty?) %>
    183:                    <center>
    184:                            <div style="background-color:lightyellow; border:     1px solid gold; width: 95%; padding: 3px; text-align: left;">
    185:                                    <font color=green>

app/views/layouts/loggedin.rhtml:182:in `_run_rhtml_app47views47layouts47loggedin46rhtml'
app/controllers/testcases_controller.rb:1337:in `view'
```

I would be glad to here the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first line can be simplified to `<% unless flash[:notice].blank? && flash[:warning].blank? %>` - you use blank later, why not use it at the start?

Comment: Beware that `and` and `or` are not the same as `&&` and `||`. More info can be found [here](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)

Comment: @zwippie Is this directed at me? It's pretty clear what the whole posted code is trying to do, in context, is my suggestion incorrect? Looks to me like simple blank string checks rather than any usage that would make `or` a better choice. Happy to be corrected if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @Matt, my comment was meant for Bindu. Your suggestion in your first comment seems ok te me.

Comment: This issue got resolved the error was thrown in only one machine and after emptying the browser data solved the issue.